# EXC_BAD ACCESS code=1 when <BACK is pressed using Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, uisplitviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

The configuration I'm pursuing is a Navigation Controller embedded as a Detail View in a Split View Controller. Inside that controller I have a Button that push to another View Controller. So far so good.

When I pressed the Back Button is when everything goes BAD. The previous controller is correctly shown, but an instante later the view appears there is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS with code = 1.

Comment: Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint or turning on NSZombies?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell you where you went wrong if we don't know what you are doing... Please post the code (how do you create the VC and how do you go back?)

Comment: [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

Comment: I turned on NSZombies and the problem is that a message is sent to a deallocated instance, in this case is the dismissed controller.